# BeautifulSoup - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to get the price information on second hand Iphone7 smartphones. After I use the bs4 library to get the relevant html and use BeautifulSoup to create an object called 'soup', I search for each product's information by using the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
products = soup.find_all('div', class_='feed-item sc-gqjmRU igneJk')
```

This does give me the correct html information about each product. Now I go one layer deeper to see the descriptions for each product:

```
descriptions = [x.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf') for x in products]
```

The code given above works fine. However this is not the description I want. It is a rather crude form of what I am looking for. To get only the descriptions I mentioned I need to write something like this (.getText() needs to be added):

```
descriptions = [x.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf').getText() for x in products]
```

This gives me the following error:

> ----> 1 descriptions = [x.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf').getText() for x in products]
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'

However, the code below works fine:

```
descriptions = [x.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf') for x in products]
descriptions[0].getText()
```

descriptions[0] should be the same thing as the value of x.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf') that we get from the first iteration.

My question is: **Since they should give the same value (both x.find and description[0]), why one gives an error whereas the other works?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: One of your descriptions, not necessarily the one at index 0 but maybe later, is None.

Comment: By the way, very nicely explained and a really great first question, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that one of the products does not have an element matching `.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf')` search criteria.

You could add this extra check and do:

```
for product in products:
    description_element = product.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf')
    description = description_element.get_text() if description_element else "No Description"

    print(description)
```

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile and providing a code, this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you run `descriptions = [x.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf').getText() for x in products]`, this uses `getText()` on every instance of `x.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf')`.  All it takes is one of these to be `None` for the whole iteration to not work. When you create the `descriptions` list as `descriptions = [x.find('p', class_='sc-kAzzGY kZncUf') for x in products]`, there is more than one element in this list, where the first one is not `None` but at least one of the other elements is.